# How to change the color of link button in .erb template

Tags: html, css, erb

I want to change the color of the "Explore" and 'Submit Your project" button in the erb template .Currently they are blue coloured .If Shoud i use a div to do this or is there any other way too

```
<div id="header">
     <%= link_to 'Explore', explore_path %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <%= link_to 'Submit Your Project', submit_path %>

      <div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <h1 id="lockitron_header"><a href="/"><%= Settings.product_name %></a></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's going on with all those `&nbsp;`s?  Is it to add extra width to the element?  Because that's what css is for.

Comment: you need to write css style sheet. it's not ruby on rails question.

Comment: Max Williams : &nbsp is for creating space .Is there an alternative to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `style` for inline css

```
<%= link_to 'Explore', explore_path, style: "color: red;" %>
```

or use `class`

```
<%= link_to 'Explore', explore_path, class: "link-color" %>
```

and in stylesheet

```
.link-color{
  color: "red";
}
```

Comment: Doing it via class and corresponding stylesheet is better.  Save style tags for when you need data-driven styling.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes, I have edited the answer now, it tells how we can use both according to the need.

Answer (score 2):

Just give class or id to your anchors and then use css to give them different colour

```
<%= link_to 'Explore', explore_path, class: "black" %>
<%= link_to 'Submit Your Project', submit_path, class: "black" %>
```

And in css

```
.black {color: #000;}
```

This is very basic CSS and HTML You should checkout [`CSS`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) and [`HTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)