# ruby - How to change font color array value

Tags: ruby

With ERB, print into HTML.
whenever the array value is divisible by 2, I want to change font color to red.
whenever the value contains 3, I want to change the font color to blue.

How do I write input.txt ?

This is code of example.rb

```
require 'erb'

input_file = "input.txt"

output_file = "output.html"

prime_number = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 
59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

str = ""
File.open(input_file, "r:UTF-8") do |io|
  str = io.read
end

erb = ERB.new(str)
result = erb.result(binding)

File.open(output_file, "w") do |io|
  io.write result
end
```

This is input.txt

```
<% prime_number.each |a| % 2 == 0 do %>
<% puts a %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please post your code, so that people can suggest accordingly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of How to change the color of link button in .erb template - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550699/how-to-change-the-color-of-link-button-in-erb-template

Comment: @tukan How would you know that it is a possible duplicate of that question...He never mentioned that it is a link or button or something...

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna Sorry. I posted my code.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna true.

Comment: Add a div before `puts a` like `<div style="color:red"> <% puts a %> </div>` That should do the trick I guess...

Comment: And in the block where you are checking for another condition you can use similar div, but change color:red to color:blue...